# Making all Links in a Web View open in the Default Browser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I have a web view that displays a web page but I want all links on that page to open in the default browser. How would I do this?

Comment: Why on earth is this tagged with nstableview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `WebPolicyDelegate` so that any attempts to navigate are cancelled, and the URL opened in the default browser.